# Pandas Data Frame Partial String Replace

Tags: python, string, pandas, replace, partial

Given this data frame:

```
import pandas as pd
d=pd.DataFrame({'A':['a','b',99],'B':[1,2,'99'],'C':['abcd99',4,5]})
d

    A   B   C
0   a   1   abcd*
1   b   2   4
2   99  99  5
```

I want to replace all 99s in the entire data frame with asterisks.
I've tried this:

```
d.replace('99','*')
```

...but it only worked in the case of the string 99 in column B.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `numpy`s character functions

```
d.values[:] = np.core.defchararray.replace(d.values.astype(str), '99', '*')
d

   A  B      C
0  a  1  abcd*
1  b  2      4
2  *  *      5
```

***naive time test***

[image]

Answer (score 4):

This will do the job:

```
import pandas as pd
d=pd.DataFrame({'A':['a','b',99],'B':[1,2,'99'],'C':['abcd99',4,5]})
d=d.astype(str)
d.replace('99','*',regex=True)
```

which gives

```
    A   B   C
0   a   1   abcd*
1   b   2   4
2   *   *   5
```

Note that this creates a new dataframe. You can also do that inplace instead:

```
d.replace('99','*',regex=True,inplace=True)
```

Answer (score 3):

If you want to replace all the `99`s , try using regex

`>>> d.astype(str).replace('99','*',regex=True)`

```
    A   B   C
0   a   1   abcd*
1   b   2   4
2   *   *   5
```

Answer (score 2):

Problem is values `99` in column A and B are of different types:

```
>>> type(d.loc[2,"A"])
<class 'int'>
>>> type(d.loc[2,"B"])
<class 'str'>
```

You can cast your dataframe to string type via [df.astype()](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.astype.html) and then replace, resulting in:

```
>>> d.astype(str).replace("99","*")
   A  B       C
0  a  1  abcd99
1  b  2       4
2  *  *       5
```

---

Edit: using regex is the correct solution as given by other answers. I for some reason missed the abcd* in your DataFrame.

Will leave this here, just in case it is helpful to someone else.